# Does the AI "cheat-peek" when selecting which Pokémon to send out?

Tags: pokemon-stadium, pokemon-stadium-2

In Pokémon Stadium (mostly 1, but also 2) I have played around with save-states a bit.

It seems that in the battles where both I and the AI select 3 out of 6 Pokémon for battle, the AI is affected by my choices, both in terms of which 3 Pokémon it chooses, and in which one is sent out first.

In theory, the AI should not "know" which 3 Pokémon I chose.

Is there any relationship between my choices and that of the AI, or am I just imagining things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is definitely a fixed outcome of events, specifically for Pokémon Stadium 2, so no, it's not just a coincidence. I used to mess around with the save states when I played the Stadium 2 emulator. The outcomes for your Pokémon selection, and the way the battle plays out are fixed. When I played Stadium 1, I could manipulate the outcomes by going back to a save state, so a move with lower accuracy could miss, or I could avoid a crit to see if it works.

This isn't a thing in Stadium 2. I don't know if I'd call it a cheat peek, but your decisions create a certain outcome path. Meaning that, if you start a battle, and your opponent lands a stun spore, you getting hit is determined by some of your decisions. I tried to abuse the save state in 2, and it didn't work. I could only change the outcome if I maybe used a different move or switched out. I don't think it's that complex, but there are more fixed outcomes in Stadium 2 than 1. It's not necessarily cheat peeking though.

Answer (score 3):

After some research I've looked and from my limited knowledge I can say **it's likely just you**.

Based on some sleuthing Pokemon Stadium (and likely 2) [are based on Pokemon Red / Green](https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/3d2xvs/til_that_when_it_was_time_to_make_pokemon_stadium/) which after looking at some of the [source code for Pokemon Red](https://github.com/pret/pokered) and searching online for reports I don't think it peeks at your party to calculate it's next move.

From the [limited source code for Stadium](https://github.com/pret/pokestadium) I can also say there's no peeking that I could see here. This is all very basic looking and possibly not a direct source. Satoru Iwata did port the code based on the linked interview and could have possibly changed it in Stadium and Stadium 2 however.

Comment: Thanks for this. I believe in RBY the order is always fixed, whereas in stadium it changes?

Comment: I believe it could be down to how it compares Pokemon, The line from Red makes it seem like it's constant yes. Here is Red's function to send out `EnemySendOutFirstMon`: https://github.com/pret/pokered/blob/master/engine/battle/core.asm#L1381

Comment: Also a good chunk of Stadium's source code hasn't been reversed and put on Github from what I can tell so it could be more complicated.

Answer (score -2):

This question isn't answerable via traditional means, but from my personal experience with programming and other Nintendo games, I'd say likely the opponent's pokemon isn't based on your pokemon specifically, but rather it's based on your inputs leading up to the fight.

try picking the same pokemon twice (even though it won't let you) before you pick the rest of your party, compare that to the normal where you pick your pokemon once from a savestate, if it's different it's based on your input if it's the same it might be based on your party?

Sorry, this is a little late, hope it helps, this is the best test I could think of for this.